# работа нескольких пользователей с git

Tags: git

На сервере установлен git работал с ним только один человек, но сейчас к проекту присоединились еще два человека. Тут вопрос как сделать так что бы при работе с сайтом они работали только со своими ветками? Т.е что бы если юзер подрубается по фтп у него активна своя ветка. А для админа к примеру по умолчанию ветка master.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не совсем понятно как связана работа с `Git` и `FTP`. Вам нужно бы изучить матчасть, основы `Git`.

Например, если вам нужно распределить работу разработчиков, то можно использовать такой подход. Создается `bare` репозиторий (голый, без файлов) и с него клонируются разработчиские директории + тестовый сайт + продакшен.

Каждый разработчик работает с любой веткой в своей директории и когда задача готова делает `git merge` например в ветку test или master и `git push` в удаленный репозиторий, а потом уже на тестовом сайте или продакшене соответственно делается `git pull` с удаленного репозитория.

Ссылки по теме:

- [Основы Git](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git)
- [Git flow](https://habrahabr.ru/post/106912/)
- [Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com)
- [Gitolite](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/Git-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-Gitolite)
- [Gitosis](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/Git-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-Gitosis)

Comment: Хм, век живи - век учись. Не думал о том, что можно так вывернуться в отсутствие команд управления доступом в гит. Но надо сказать, что способ несколько тяжеловат и неудобен для восприятия.

Comment: @AK в смысле вывернутся? Разработчиские поодомены для сайта это по вашему не нормально? Как работать по другому, если на локальных компьютерах нету сервера?

Comment: Подправлю свой вопрос, у нас есть удаленный репоз. на гит хабе, есть несколько веток в которых идет работа , работал 1 чел. Сейчас +2 , и у всех доступ один, т.е логин и пароль к ssh для подключения к серваку. И получается если зайдет 1 и выберет свою ветку, то к примеру у 2-го автоматом переключиться ветка, на ветку 1-го. И как я понял "голый" репоз. это и есть то то самый который лежит на гит хабе? И не совсем понял что нужно сделать чтоб зашел первый прог. выбрал свою ветку и норм работал, параллельно зашел второй также выбрал свою ветку и начал работать не мешая первому.

Comment: @SergeyZaigraev в вашем случае "голый" это да, на гитхабе. Не путайте пожалуйста работу с Гитов и с файловой системой. Если вам нужен доступ для разрабов к файлам, которые на разных ветках, то создайте разные физические директории, в которых и будут активные нужные директории

Comment: сделал так , как вы посоветовали, у каждого разраба своя копия файлов, на разных поддоменах и у каждого своя ветка.

Answer (score 3):

Это невозможно сделать средствами самого `git` или средствами операционной системы. Доступ бинарен: либо доступ есть, либо его нет.

Вам нужно смотреть в сторону различных надстроек над `git` -- `gitolite`, `gitosys` (давно не обновлялся) и `gitlab` (не помню точно, можно ли там на уровне отдельных веток рулить правами).

Вот, например, кратко базовые возможности `gitolite`:

```
Права могут быть указаны следующим образом:

    R - только чтение
    RW - чтение добавление коммитов, запрещен rewind (push --force)
    RW+ - полный доступ
    RWC - возможность создавать ветку
    RWD - возможность удалять ветку
    - запретить запись

объекты доступа могут быть:

    master@ - ветки
    ref/tags - теги (версии)
    NAME/имя_файла - имена файлов/каталогов
```

Answer (score 3):

> Тут вопрос как сделать так что бы при работе с сайтом они работали только со своими ветками?

На мой взгляд, этот вопрос имеет что-то общее с использованием `private` переменных и методов. Даже если вы "спрячете" некоторый объект, то при желании, используя рефлексию, с ним всё равно можно сделать что угодно.

Поэтому предлагаю нетехническое решение:

1. **Договоритесь. Установите правила командной работы с Git и рассчитывайте на конструктивные намерения и здравый смысл сотрудников.**

   В частности:

   - Как именуются коммиты?
   - Как создаются и именуются ветки?
   - Кто может пушить в ветки, каждый в свою или можно и к соседу?
   - Кто имеет право пушить в master? (Вероятно, только тимлид.)
   - Кто имеет право принимать запросы на слияние в master? (Аналогично.)
2. Убедитесь в достаточных навыках работы с Git у каждого сотрудника. Судя по вопросам на StackOverflow, подавляющее большинство проблем в командной работе возникает неумышленно, просто от непонимания происходящего.

Указанные в соседних ответах технические решения хороши, когда у вас уже есть явным образом установленные правила и вы хотите поддержать их, а также застраховаться от нечаянных или намеренных деструктивных операций. Но они не заменят собой правил и взаимопонимания в команде.

Comment: спасибо за советы.