# Как ограничить права на push в определенные ветки git?

Tags: git

Есть репозиторий с ветками `master`, и отходящей от нее `dev`, в которые по задумке, могут делать `push` только те пользователи, у которых есть на это права, остальные могут только забирать из них код (`fetch rebase...`), и отправлять `merge request`, так, чтобы другие у кого такие права есть, сами вливали изменения если они устраивают.

Или другими словами одна группа разработчиков может изменять `master` и `dev`, другая работает только через `merge request`, и должны пройти проверку первой.

Как настроить такое поведение `git`, чтобы если у пользователя нет прав на  `push` в запрещенные ветки, а он пытается его сделать, то получал `reject` в каком-то виде?

Comment: А какой сервер-то? Github, gitlab, gitea, просто ssh?

Comment: фактически дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/551100/178576

Comment: @Alexey Ten на гит лаб но конечно хотелось бы решение не зависящее от конкретной реализации, если это вообще возможно. Но если нет, то по краиней мере что-бы с gitlab работало.

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html наверное это надо почитать